# Hibernate criteria, distinct association property

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, criteria, hibernate-criteria

Say I have at least these two entities:

```
class Person {
   String firstname, lastname;

   Address address;

   ManyOtherPropertiesAndEntities ...;
}

class Address {
      String street;
      Country country;   
}
```

Now, I would like to query the Person table and **ONLY** Persons that live on different streets.

That is, **ignore all Persons that live on same street**, and return only one of these Person, any one.

How can I perform such a query?

Is that possibly using **Criteria**?

```
 Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Person.class, "person");

 Criteria addressCriteria = criteria.createCriteria("address")

 criteria.setProjection(
                    Projections.distinct(
                        Projections.projectionList().add(Projections.property("address.street"))
                    )
            );
```

This doesnt really work.

I've also tried to do:

```
projectionList.add( Projections.sqlProjection("DISTINCT ON ( address.street ), ... ", columns.toArray(new String[columns.size()]), types.toArray(new Type[types.size()])));
```

But also fruitless.

**>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>EDIT<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<**

I was able to get this to run, and generate an SQL query that actually returns results in a pure sql mode, but seems to return zero in hibernate:

```
List<String> columns = Lists.lst();
                                        List<Type> types     = Lists.lst();

                                        bondCriteria.setProjection(
                                                Projections.sqlProjection ("DISTINCT ON ( tvmux2_.polarization ) * "
                                                        , columns.toArray (new String[columns.size()])
                                                        , types.toArray   (new Type[types.size()])
                                                )

                                                // Projections.projectionList().add(Projections.distinct(Projections.property("polarization")))
                                        );

                                        ResultTransformer resultTransformer = new ResultTransformer() {
                                                @Override
                                                public List transformList( List collection ) {
                                                        return null;
                                                }

                                                @Override
                                                public Object transformTuple( Object[] tuple, String[] aliases ) {
                                                        return null;
                                                }
                                        };

                                        bondCriteria.setResultTransformer(resultTransformer);
```

*** ITS 2017 and SO still hasn't included a proper editor to easily be able to format code so that indentation and copy and paste is not a complete hell. Feel free to scroll horizontally. ***

THis generates teh following query basically

```
select DISTINCT ON ( tvmux2_.polarization ) *  from TvChannelBond this_ inner join TvChannel tvchannel1_ on this_.channel=tvchannel1_.id inner join TvMux tvmux2_ on this_.mux=tvmux2_.id where this_.enabled=true order by tvmux2_.polarization asc limit 100
```

**which does return results in a non hibernate mode.**

However, since sqlProjection method requires the supplementation of 3 params, I am not sure what to add to the second and third params. Types can not be other than predefined Hibernate types just as DOUBLE, STRING and so on.

When **debugging** into the **resultTransformer**, it gets into transformTuple with zero length **tuple[] and aliases[].**

Might have to do with the **sqlProjection zero length** types and columns lists.

Comment: Just a question: why would you use Hibernate Criteria at all? It's deprecated and not supported. Btw, for this kind of requirement, I'd suggest going with native query.

Comment: @galovics There is already a big criteria query being in place. This is just an addon option and i'd like to avoid having to rewrite the entire query builder for this case. 

Criteria queries deprecated? What is suggested now? Don't say HQL.

Comment: @galovics See this https://stackoverflow.com/a/45325401/961018 ... question is now how to turn that sql projection to hibernate criteria.

Comment: Instead of Hibernate's proprietary Criteria-API you're encouraged to use the [Criteria-API](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.5/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html) that's now in the JPA standard.

Comment: ^ ^ updated with an edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL, you could do it like this:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM Address a
INNER JOIN Person p ON ...
GROUP BY a.Street
HAVING p.id = MIN(p.id)
```

This statement selects for every distinct `Street` from `Address` the `Person` with the minimum `id` value. Instead of `MIN(p.id)` you can of course use any other field and aggregate function which will match exactly one person per street; `MAX(p.id)` will work, `MIN(p.lastname)` won't if there can be more than one "Smith" in a street.

Can you transform the above SQL to your Criteria query?

Comment: Updated with an edit. Based on a different sql query, found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45325401/961018

Note that I am aware that the tables and properties have changed but that shouldn't really matter here.