# SQL - Fetch any rows based on a distinct property, no duplicates

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate

Is it possible to run a query, that says fetch all for this table that have distinct property and select any matched row for that distinct property, doesn't matter to unique/distinct rows based on just one property.

If

```
row1 : name:a, age:10, street:james street
row2 : name:b, age:15, street:peter street
row3 : name:c, age:17, street:james street
```

Now I would like the query to return

```
row2 and either row1 or row2
```

Doesn't matter if it is row1 or row2, i don't care.

Now, ideally i'd like to perform this using hibernate criteria queries because I already have a query builder for that and I am just adding this as an option.

Comment: Each row in your example data set looks distinct to me; could you clarify what you mean by "distinct"?

Comment: @MickMnemonic There are two on the same street. Based on street distinct is what is meant here. But I found out the answer to this one: 

select distinct on (street) * from tbl works

Comment: Question now is how to use it with hibernate criteria, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45324808/hibernate-criteria-distinct-association-property?noredirect=1#comment77611496_45324808

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears as if

```
select distinct on (street) * from tbl
```

works.

Answer (score 0):

You could try Projections: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html#querycriteria-projection

Something like this could work. It will select unique results based on "street" property:

```
List results = session.createCriteria(Entity.class)
    .setProjection( Projections.projectionList()
        .add(Projections.distinct(Projections.property("street")))
    )
    .list();
```

Comment: I've tried that. The problems is that I can't get it to distinct on a association property. 

Projections.projectionList().add(Projections.distinct(Projections.property("address.street")))

leads an error : 

could not resolve property: address.street of: mypackage.entities.Person

The actual hibernate question is here, I see this doesn't mention association: 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45324808/hibernate-criteria-distinct-association-property?noredirect=1#comment77611496_45324808

Comment: Comment formatting here sucks, here is a better view: https://hastebin.com/lilirulume.scala

Comment: updated https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45324808/hibernate-criteria-distinct-association-property?noredirect=1#comment77611496_45324808

With an edit that almost works. Runs sql that returns rows in pure sql but zero length in hibernate.